# implement a url sheme protocol

Tags: xcode, url-scheme

I know that in `Xcode` it's easy to create a url scheme.
Like I input `tg://123` and telegram will open.
How do I implement a custom url scheme like `hello://` and my program will open?

It there a way to achieve that? I haven't found out any solution yet.

Comment: I think that this problem has nothing to do with Qt but with your OS since if you used another library that was not Qt and you wanted to do the same then the answer must be the same.

Comment: True. I'm thinking whether there is a universal library in Qt5 can achieve this.

Comment: Qt5 is not used to configure the OS. That is the task of the OS.

Comment: Is this about deep linking?

Comment: @Coel Please check my updated answer to the custom URL scheme document provided by doc.qt.io I have mentioned some code for your reference, but if you want to check the full document and process step by step as per the given link in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

## XCode Custom URL Scheme

Below document/content is provided by [https://developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app).

I just put some specifics lines of the document/content.

Support a custom URL scheme by doing the following:

```
myphotoapp:albumname?name=”albumname”
myphotoapp:albumname?index=1
```

#### Register Your URL Scheme

Below document/document is provided by [doc.qt.io](http://doc.qt.io)

- Specify the prefix you use for your URLs in the URL Schemes box.
- Choose a role for your app:

  - Specify an editor role for URL schemes that you define.
  - Specify a viewer role for schemes that your app adopts, but does not
    define.
- Specify an identifier for your app.

For more reference and check step by step custom URL Scheme, please check [https://developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app)

## Update QT Custom URL Scheme

#### [QT Custom URL Scheme](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineurlschemehandler.html)

To implement a custom URL scheme for `QtWebEngine`, you first have to create an instance of `QWebEngineUrlScheme` and register it using `QWebEngineUrlScheme::registerScheme()`.

Note: Make sure that you create and register the scheme object before the `QGuiApplication` or `QApplication` object is instantiated.

Then you must create a class derived from QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler, and reimplement the `requestStarted()` method.

Finally, install the scheme handler object via `QWebEngineProfile::installUrlSchemeHandler()` or `QQuickWebEngineProfile::installUrlSchemeHandler()`.

```
class MySchemeHandler : public QWebEngineUrlSchemeHandler
{
public:
    MySchemeHandler(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    void requestStarted(QWebEngineUrlRequestJob *request)
    {
        // ....
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QWebEngineUrlScheme scheme("myscheme");
    scheme.setSyntax(QWebEngineUrlScheme::Syntax::HostAndPort);
    scheme.setDefaultPort(2345);
    scheme.setFlags(QWebEngineUrlScheme::SecureScheme);
    QWebEngineUrlScheme::registerScheme(scheme);

    // ...
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    // ...

    // installUrlSchemeHandler does not take ownership of the handler.
    MySchemeHandler *handler = new MySchemeHandler(parent);
    QWebEngineProfile::defaultProfile()->installUrlSchemeHandler("myscheme", handler);
}
```

Comment: The content mentioned was for ``XCode`` not for ``Qt5``.

Comment: Calling ``myscheme://`` still can't open the app. How to register the protocol like the ``Xcode`` does?